# The Borel–Cantelli lemma proof

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation, borel-cantelli-lemmas

As part of the Borel–Cantelli lemma's proof we see the following:

[image]

[image]

Can you please explain me why

[image]

Am I correct in reading the inf of a prob as the smallest probability among all the [image] for all the possible $N\geq 1$ values? Which would then tend to $0$ as $N$ tends to infinity?

Comment: From $\Pr[A\cap B] \leq \min(\Pr[A],\Pr[B])$ (is that clear to you?), you get that $\Pr[\bigcap_{n=1}^N A_n] \leq \min_{1\leq n\leq N}\Pr[A_n]$ for any countable family of events $(A_n)_n$ and any fixed $N\geq 1$; and then, letting $N\to\infty$ you get $\Pr[\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n] \leq \inf_{n\geq 1}\Pr[A_n]$. (It's an infimum, not a maximum, as it's no longer guaranteed that the "minimum" is achieved by any particular $n$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are any two events. Then $$P(A\cap B)\le\min\{P(A),P(B)\}$$ since $P(A\cap B)\le P(A)$ and $P(A\cap B)\le P(B)$. In the proof, we have a countable number of events and the minimum might not exist. Hence, we take the infimum of these events and obtain
$$
P\biggl(\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty E_n\biggr)\le\inf_{N\ge1}P\biggl(\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty E_n\biggr).
$$